# If $A$ and$ I+AB$ are invertible, show $I+BA$ is also invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse

Show that if $A$ and $I+AB$ are invertible, then $I+BA$ is also invertible with
$$(I+BA)^{-1} = A^{-1}(I+AB)^{-1}A$$

Comment: Multiply $I+BA$ on the left with $A^{-1}(I+AB)^{-1}A$ try to simplify it using the distributive property. Then do the same on the right.

Comment: Three answers, none from me, and yet mine is the only vote for the question so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** Just do it. Use the fact that

$$ (I + BA) A^{-1} = A^{-1} + B = A^{-1}(I+AB).$$

to show that

$$ (I + BA) A^{-1} (I+AB)^{-1} A = I.$$

Comment: Is it also necessary to show  $A^{-1} (I+AB)^{-1} A (I + BA)= I$?

Comment: @mezhang For general square matrices $M, N$, if we know that $M N = I$, then $N M = I$.

Comment: @mezhang if a square matrix has a one sided inverse, then it has an inverse. CalvinLin: Your comment is only true for square matrices.

Comment: @Tim Could you show me a proof for your statement? I don't want to raise a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: @mezhang Check the lemma in my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280884/prove-that-matrix-a-have-inverse/280892#280892

Comment: @Tim Agreed. Edited it to add 'square'.

Comment: @mezhang It follows from the submultiplicativity of the determinant that if a square matrix has a one-sided inverse, that it is invertible. The rest follows from the uniqueness of the two-sided inverse.

Answer (score 3):

$$
(I + BA) = A^{-1}(I + AB)A \Rightarrow (I + BA)^{-1} = A^{-1}(I + AB)^{-1}A
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\,A^{-1}C^{-1}A=(A^{-1}CA)^{-1}\,$ , we get with $\,C=I+AB\,$ :

$$(I+BA)\left(A^{-1}(I+AB)^{-1}A\right)=(I+BA)(A^{-1}(I+AB)A)^{-1}=$$

$$(I+BA)(I+BA)^{-1}=I$$